Is the United States Olympic Committee actually in danger of trademark dilution?
I am aware that for most trademarks, there is a concept called "Trademark Dilution", where a failure of a company to enforce their trademarks makes it harder to enforce future trademarks claim in the future.
However, unlike most other trademarks, which are either automatic or are registered at an executive agency, the trademarks relating to the United States Olympic Committee were specifically granted from a bill granted by congress - I.E. not through the usual process.
I was wondering if this meant the usual rules regarding trademark dilution still applied, because the trademark is literally in the books? If it does still apply, can congress just pass the same law again to "undo" the dilution?

That's not what trademark dilution means: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trademark_dilution "Trademark dilution is a trademark law concept giving the owner of a famous trademark standing to forbid others from using that mark in a way that would lessen its uniqueness. In most cases, trademark dilution involves an unauthorized use of another's trademark on products that do not compete with, and have little connection with, those of the trademark owner."
